# Help with justification of running text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, cv

This is my class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Arponcv}[28/9/2018 custom CV class]
\LoadClass{article}

\usepackage[scaled=1.05,proportional,lightcondensed]{zlmtt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\datedsection[2]{%%
  \addvspace{3ex}%%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-3pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%%
  {\Large\scshape\ttfamily\bfseries#1\hspace{\fill}#2}\par\addvspace{2ex}
  }

\newcommand\datedsubsection[2]{%%
  \addvspace{1ex}%%
  \noindent{\large\scshape\ttfamily\bfseries#1\hspace{\fill}#2}\par\addvspace{1ex}}

\newcommand\information[2]{%%
  \noindent{\normalsize\scshape\ttfamily#1\hspace{\fill}#2}\par\addvspace{5pt}}
```

This is my .tex file.

```
\documentclass{Arponcv}
\begin{document}
\datedsection{Education}{}
     \datedsubsection{Bachelor of Science}{2015-Now}
         \information{Department of Nuclear Engineering,}{} \information{University of Dhaka,
         Dhaka, Bangladesh}{}
         \information{Current CGPA (Up to 6th Semester): 3.72}{}
     \datedsubsection{Higher Secondary Certificate}{2014}
         \information{St. Joseph Higher Secondary School, Dhaka, Bangladesh}{}
         \information{GPA: 5.00 out of 5.00}{}
     \datedsubsection{Secondary School Certificate}{2012}
         \information{St. Joseph Higher Secondary School, Dhaka, Bangladesh}{}
         \information{GPA: 5.00 out of 5.00}{}

\datedsection{Standardized Tests}{}
     \datedsubsection{Graduate Record Examination (GRE)}{2018}
         \information{Total- 329. Quantitative Reasoning: 170, Verbal Reasoning: 159}{} 
         \information{Analytical Writing Analysis: 5.0}{}
     \datedsubsection{Test Of English as a Foreign Language (TOEFL)}{2018}
         \information{Total: 111. Reading: 29, Listening: 29, Speaking: 27, Writing: 26}{}

\datedsection{Research Interests}{}

\datedsection{Research Experience}{}
     \datedsubsection{Undergraduate Thesis}{Sept 2018-Now}
         \information{Title: Computer code development for steady-state neutronics analysis of a novel reactor core.}{}
         \information{Description: I am currently working on developing a computer code to numerically approximate the steady-state neutronics of a novel reactor core.}{} 
     \datedsubsection{Undergraduate Project}{Sept 2017-March 2018}
         \information{Title: Demonstration of axial neutron flux distribution in a hypothetical reactor core employing control pellets (control material in pellet form).}{}
         \information{Description: I demonstrated an evenly balanced axial flux distribution that can be generated if hypothetical control pellets (control material in pellet form) are used instead of regular single-piece control rods. Regular control rods generate uneven axial flux distribution when partially inserted.}{}

\datedsection{Industrial Attachment}{}
     \datedsubsection{Institute of Electronics}{March 2018-April 2018}
         \information{Atomic Energy Research Establishment (AERE), Savar, Dhaka, Bangladesh. A facility of Bangladesh Atomic Energy Commission (BAEC)}{}

\datedsection{Prizes, Awards and Grants}{}
     \datedsubsection{}{}

\datedsection{Work Experience}{}
     \datedsubsection{Administrative Experience}{??}
     \datedsubsection{Teaching Experience}{??}

\datedsection{Volunteer Work}{}

\datedsection{Computer and Programming Skills}{}

\end{document}
```

I want to define the `\information` command, which is defined in the class file, in such a way that whatever I write in the .tex file under `\information{}{}` comes out fully justified.

Currently it gives some outputs as justified, and some outputs as left aligned.

For illustration:

The way the title and descriptions of research experiences came out is satisfactory.

[image]

But the description of the industrial attachment isn't justified. Or maybe it is justified to a different margin.

[image]

How can I remedy this situation?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the word "Bangladesh" near the top of the second page isn't hyphenated and hence protrudes into the right-hand margin? If so, try adding the instruction `\hyphenation{bang-la-desh}` in the preamble.

Comment: unrelated to the typesetting, but  in the class file the date is in the wrong format `28/9/2018 ` should be `2018/09/28` or `2018-09-28` (yyy-mm-dd) otherwise any date comparisons will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you're mainly concerned with the fact that, in the section "Industrial Attachment", the word "Bangladesh" isn't hyphenated and thus sticks out into the right-hand margin.

I can think of two remedies:

- Inform LaTeX how to hyphenate the word "Bangladesh", by placing the instruction `\hyphenation{bangla-desh}` in the preamble. Potential downside: Some people might object to hyphenating names of countries. (I'm not one of these people, but ...)
- Simply drop the word "Bangladesh". Potential downside: The folks reading your cv might be unsure *which city* called "Dhaka" is being referred to. Honestly, if they really are unsure, they are in lots of trouble -- and you almost certainly don't want to work for them anyway...

Whatever else you may do, please use `--` ("en-dash") rather than just `-` ("simple or short dash") to connect date ranges. E.g., please write `March 2018--April 2018`, not `March 2018-April 2018`. The document contains four instances of where an en-dash should be used, at least in fine typography.

[image]

```
\datedsection{Industrial Attachment, Solution 1}{}
\datedsubsection{Institute of Electronics}{March 2018--April 2018}
\information{Atomic Energy Research Establishment (AERE), Savar, Dhaka, 
 Bangladesh. A facility of the Bangladesh Atomic Energy Commission (BAEC).}{}


\datedsection{Industrial Attachment, Solution 2}{}
\datedsubsection{Institute of Electronics}{March 2018--April 2018}
\information{Atomic Energy Research Establishment (AERE), Savar, Dhaka. 
A facility of the Bangladesh Atomic Energy Commission (BAEC).}{}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that LaTeX can't make a good choice about how to break the line.  If it breaks before "Bangladesh", then there will be too much white space in the line:  in other words, the line will be "underfull".  LaTeX winds up choosing between two evils:  underfull line vs protruding into the margin.  Of these two, it decides that protruding into the margin is the lesser evil.

**Approach 1: inserting a line break**

You can see this by inserting a `\linebreak` before "Bangladesh".

```
\information{Atomic Energy Research Establishment (AERE), Savar, Dhaka,\linebreak Bangladesh. A facility of Bangladesh Atomic Energy Commission (BAEC)}{}
```

which will result in

[image]

If you're fine with that appearance, the story ends there.

**Approach 2: rewording to avoid the dilemma for LaTeX**

Alternatively, you can try to reword your paragraph there so that LaTeX isn't forced into making this sort of decision.

I really don't know the importance of all the wording, but merely rearranging the information in that line as follows

```
\information{Atomic Energy Research Establishment (AERE).  A facility of Bangladesh Atomic Energy Commission (BAEC), Savar, Dhaka, Bangladesh. }{}
```

results in

[image]

Maybe this works for you, maybe it doesn't.

**Approach 3: format paragraphs `\raggedright`**

My personal bias is to say that in a resume, full justification looks bad.  So many lines are potentially short.  As a result, portions of the resume/cv look *ragged right* and others fully justified.  Personally, I would stick with a ragged right approach throughout, but that's opinion, nothing more.

However, even in this case `\raggedright` still results in the offending protrusion into the right margin.

**Approach 4: inserting `\newline`**

Instead of `\linebreak`, you could then use, `\newline`.  This gives the following result

[image]

**Approach 5: adding new hyphenation rules**

Then there's always the option of changing the hyphenation rules for Bangladesh.  Maybe something like `\hyphenation{bangla-desh}` (or otherwise as you see fit).  This results in

[image]